# Phone Gap FileTransfer plugin upload issue

Tags: cordova

I am getting a native code error with phonegap File Transfer upload:

> can not read property upload of undefined

I am using the Apache cordova template inside the visual studio 2013 wit ripple.

This is my js code.

```
function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}


    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
        // console.log(imageURI);
        alert("Imagecalled");
        // Get image handle
        //
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
        uploadPhoto(imageURI);
    }


function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

    alert("uploadPhoto");
    debugger;
    var objUrl = _ServicesUrl._SecondServicePath + _ServicePage._BaseServicePage + _WcfFunctionUrl._ImageUpload;
    var serverUrl = objUrl;


    //var fileUploadOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
    //fileUploadOptions.fileKey = "file";
    //fileUploadOptions.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //fileUploadOptions.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    //fileUploadOptions.chunkedMode = true;

    //var ft = new FileTransfer();
    //ft.upload(imageURI, serverUrl, this.win, this.fail, fileUploadOptions);


    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.chunkedMode = false;

    options.fileKey = "recFile";

    var imagefilename = imageURI;

    options.fileName = imagefilename;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    alert(imagefilename);

    ft.upload(imageURI, serverUrl, win1, fail1, options);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins do not work on ripple. They execute native code. You should try using an actual emulator.

Comment: Thank's Michael , for help it's working when i try in Android phone

Comment: did any one  know how to handle multipart form data on wcf service.

Comment: you should ask that in a new question.